# Why can't I install Pyannote for Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Pyannote to use it for speech diarization.
I have a Mac.
When I ran the command to install it,

`python3 -m pip install pyannote.audio`

it gave me this error:
(sorry it's so long!)

```
Building wheels for collected packages: hmmlearn
  Building wheel for hmmlearn (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [87 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/stats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_multinomial_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gmm_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gmm_hmm_multisequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_poisson_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gmm_hmm_new.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gaussian_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_categorical_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      running build_ext
      building 'hmmlearn._hmmc' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/_hmmc.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/_hmmc.o -fvisibility=hidden -g0 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
      src/_hmmc.cpp:35:34: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
        auto log = py::array_t<double>{{n}};
                                       ^~~
      src/_hmmc.cpp:63:39: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
        auto scaling_ = py::array_t<double>{{ns}};
                                            ^~~~
      src/_hmmc.cpp:66:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:120:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:154:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:188:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:222:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:258:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:289:47: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
        auto state_sequence_ = py::array_t<ssize_t>{{ns}};
                                                    ^~~~
      src/_hmmc.cpp:293:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      3 warnings and 7 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hmmlearn
  Running setup.py clean for hmmlearn
Failed to build hmmlearn
Installing collected packages: hmmlearn, google-auth-oauthlib, asteroid-filterbanks, torch-pitch-shift, tensorboard, speechbrain, pyannote.pipeline, pyannote.metrics, torch-audiomentations, pytorch-lightning, pyannote.audio
  Running setup.py install for hmmlearn ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for hmmlearn did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [89 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/stats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      copying lib/hmmlearn/hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_multinomial_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gmm_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gmm_hmm_multisequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_poisson_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gmm_hmm_new.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_gaussian_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      copying lib/hmmlearn/tests/test_categorical_hmm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/hmmlearn/tests
      running build_ext
      building 'hmmlearn._hmmc' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/_hmmc.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/_hmmc.o -fvisibility=hidden -g0 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
      src/_hmmc.cpp:35:34: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
        auto log = py::array_t<double>{{n}};
                                       ^~~
      src/_hmmc.cpp:63:39: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
        auto scaling_ = py::array_t<double>{{ns}};
                                            ^~~~
      src/_hmmc.cpp:66:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:120:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:154:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:188:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:222:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:258:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      src/_hmmc.cpp:289:47: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
        auto state_sequence_ = py::array_t<ssize_t>{{ns}};
                                                    ^~~~
      src/_hmmc.cpp:293:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'py::gil_scoped_release'
        auto nogil = py::gil_scoped_release{};
             ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /private/var/folders/f_/x1gs70q948j_m4vpw3yw547m0000gn/T/pip-install-sb5e2tkf/hmmlearn_eca5ebd27f2a4349a00d77dd16241609/.eggs/pybind11-2.10.4-py3.10.egg/pybind11/include/pybind11/gil.h:155:5: note: 'gil_scoped_release' has been explicitly marked deleted here
          gil_scoped_release(const gil_scoped_release &) = delete;
          ^
      3 warnings and 7 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> hmmlearn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.1
[notice] To update, run: pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

I also installed the command line developer tools.
It seems like some double braces are trying to reference a function that does not exist.
Could anyone please decode this for me and let me know what I should do?

Comment: These are clang (c++) compiler error messages. Maybe installing another version (either newer or older) of clang resolves this. The installation instructions of this extension should tell.

Comment: You'd need to make sure you have the appropriate C compiler and other dependencies installed to build the package, or (possibly easier) find a pre-built binary for the package online and install that. A package manager like conda might make that very easy.

Comment: As a naive solution, you may try installing developer tools (xcode) with basic configuration. Then try to install with conda.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a MacOS with M1. This works for me:

You can try first resolve the htmmlearn problem with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge hmmlearn
```

After you can install from git repo:

```
pip install -qq https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip
```

if you had problems with qtconsole you can install it also using conda.